# Blender for Solaris 11.4

Tags: rendering

Is there any way to use Blender 2.8 in Oracle Solaris? 
Im a big fan of solaris and want to use Solaris instead of Linux. I looked at the OpenCSW (Project where thousands of Programs was portet from Linux to Solaris) but there is no Blender.

Comment: I don't think Blender is supported on Solaris yet.

Comment: It's not officially supported and there is platform dependent code, e.g. for file system interaction, threading, locks, etc. basically anything that requires interaction with the OS.

Comment: this is so sad. solaris is the only real UNIX operating system that i know and is gonna to die.

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 Not "yet". "Anymore". There used to be Solaris downloads back in the old website's days.